# WPF Ctrl+Tab Functionality in Nested Tabs

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF, when I use `Ctrl+Tab` to switch between tabs of a `TabControl`, things work as expected, switching between each tab. However, when there are nested tabs inside the parent tab, those ***nested*** tabs switch with `Ctrl+Tab` instead of the parent tabs. I want `Ctrl+Tab` to only swap the parent tab, and not swap the nested tabs. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I have tried to add external methods to force the control to switch the parent tabs instead of the nested tabs, but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: *"I am expecting like when User use CTRL+TAB only parent tab change cursor not go to inside tabs"* - This is the default behavior. Ctrl+Tab will not navigate to the children of the container by default.  Only Tab does this. Please show your layout.

Comment: @Dipesh, what do you mean by "I have tried to add external method but it's not working." Can you add the details for what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the event on the child tab items and re-raise it with the parents by doing something like this.

#### Code Behind:

```cs
        private void TabControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control 
                && e.Key == Key.Tab)
            {
                ParentTabs.RaiseEvent(e);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

And in the xaml, reference that handler:

#### Xaml:

```xml
        <TabControl x:Name="ParentTabs">
            <TabItem Header="Parent 1">
                <TextBlock Text="Parent 1" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Parent 2">
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="Sub 1" KeyDown="TabControl_KeyDown">
                        <TextBlock Text="Sub 1" />
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Sub 2" KeyDown="TabControl_KeyDown">
                        <TextBlock Text="Sub 2" />
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Sub 3" KeyDown="TabControl_KeyDown">
                        <TextBlock Text="Sub 3" />
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Parent 3">
                <TextBlock Text="Parent 3" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]